# Appium multiplatform testing - set up capabilities

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I want to be able to execute different test scenarios using Appium on different platforms. E.g. I will be doing something on web app using chrome and then checking if it had an impact on the mobile Android app on emulator.

I tried Appium and Multiremote for WebdriverIO but I cannot get the setup right for the project. I can make it work ONLY on Android or Chrome, but never as a couple. I belive, the problem is with capabilities in wdio.conf.js file:

```
export const config = {
    specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ],
    maxInstances: 10,
    capabilities: [{
        myChromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        },
        myAndroid: {
            capabilities: {
                platformName: 'Android',
                'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
                'appium:deviceName': 'Android',
                'appium:appPackage': 'com.android.settings',
                'appium:appActivity': '.Settings',
            }
        }
    }],
}
```

The session for Android does not start in this configuration even tough the emulator is up and running. How to define the capabilities for that properly?